# Assembly program exits without printing to screen (printf)

Tags: assembly, att

```
.code32
.text


.globl _start
_start:

;  .globl main
  .extern printf

  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp
  subl $4, %esp

  movl 8(%ebp), %eax 
  movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
  movl $0, %ecx


  pushl %eax
  pushl $msg2
  call printf
  add $8, %esp

  movl %ebp, %esp
  popl %ebp

  movl $1, %eax
  movl $0, %ebx
  int $0x80

.data

;  .asciz "Arg = %s"
 msg2: .asciz "Arg Count = %d"
```

Assuming that the number of arguments is 8 bytes above the base pointer, I move into eax then push eax onto the stack before the message and then call printf. However, after compiling and linking, this program just runs and exits without printing anything to the screen. Why it do this?

Assembled and linked like this:

```
as --32 select.s -o main.o
ld -m elf_i386 -I/lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lc main.o -o main
```

Comment: Make a call to `exit` instead of using int $0x80 to exit. The int doesn't flush the _C_ libraries output buffers.

Comment: It still exits without printing anything to the screen

Comment: This is a dumb question, but when you did `call exit` did you remove the code `movl $1, %eax
  movl $0, %ebx
  int $0x80`? I hope you did.

Comment: yes i did remove that code

Comment: It runs here just fine with the `call exit`. Can you add to your question how you are assembling and linking to generate the final executable.

Comment: And once you get printing going you should probably learn that when you don't use the _C_ runtime startup the parameters and provide a `_start` entry point that the parameters on the stack are different than had you linked against the _C_ runtime startup (and had a function main). When using `_start` there is no return address on the stack so the `argc` value is at `ebp+4` and the first argument pointer at ebp+8, second argument pointer at ebp+12 etc. You may wish to review the [System V i386  ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf)

Comment: Ok thank you...I will definitely look into that

Comment: Changing to ebp+4 doesn't work for me...is there a problem with the way it was assembled and linked?

Comment: I ran that code here with `call exit` instead of the `int $0x80` and it does output (albeit with the wrong number of arguments) using your commands. Side note: you can assemble and link in one command using this: `gcc -m32 select.s -o main -nostartfiles`

Comment: Glancing at the command you used to link I'm a bit surprised that even worked. linux.so.2 isn't an include. You'd normally specify it this way `ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -m elf_i386 -lc main.o -o main`

Comment: Dumb question but are you actually running the correct executable?

Comment: Unless you are doing something unusual with your controlling terminal it should work. You could always attempt to put a `\n` on the end of the string you are printing. `msg2: .asciz "Arg Count = %d\n"`

Comment: Yup that was it, it needed the newline character. I wonder why that is required with asm but not with c?